# Compiler warning or Static Analysis for violating noexcept guarantee?

Tags: c++, c++11, noexcept

I use noexcept heavily, and unfortunately if some transitive dependency ends up throwing in a rare case (unbeknownst to us), the crashes are extremely hard to debug - because `noexcept` causes `std::terminate` to get called.

Is there any way to detect these violations at compile time? In the example below 
the problem is obvious, but no compiler catches it by default. I realize it's not possible in all cases, but surely simpler cases should be possible

```
#include <stdexcept>

void baz()
{
    throw std::runtime_error("std::terminate awaits");
}

void bar()
{
    baz();
}

void foo() noexcept
{
    bar();
}
```

Link to godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/Ooet58

Are there compiler flags I don't know about? What about a static analysis tool that catches this?

Comment: Analyzing deep function calls for this seems intractable. Warning about simply using a `noexcept(false)` function seems too annoying.

Comment: I've learned to omit the `noexcept` tag unless I know for sure that my routine cannot throw.  Which usually means I only tag leaf function that do not call anything.

That being said, operator overloading slipped in a hard-to-spot function call I hadn't noticed... hello std::terminate.  sigh

Comment: I agree about "dont tag unless you know for sure", but code changes. Something that used to be a leaf function, gets refactored by someone else, which calls another function that throws.

Or, you call a user-provided callback in a noexcept function (e.g. you're writing an event loop), and that throws

Comment: How is the debugging extremely hard? Register your own terminate handler and put a break point there. Or if you're running a daemon that you cannot debug directly, print a stack trace or even better: create a core dump that can be debugged locally.

Comment: Within a single compilation unit,  this may be tractable, although I don't know of a tool which does it. But more philosophically, how should this be detected when calling functions from shared/dynamic libraries?

Comment: @André Agree regarding shared/dynamic libs. I'm not asking for a panacea :) Even single translation unit could be helpful.

Comment: @user2079303 Not saying it's "extremely hard", it's just a bigger pain in the ass than catching this at compile time, or having an actual try/catch handler. I've seen situations where there is a try/catch, but some function in the middle of a callchain was mistakenly marked noexcept, so the exception doesn't get caught.

For most C++ keywords there are compile-time guarantees. Imagine if misusing `const` resulted in a runtime `std::terminate`?

Comment: @user2079303 Yes, this does look like a duplicate!

Comment: @AlexanderKondratskiy yeah, run-time checked const would not be nice. But imagine if noexcept had same limitation that you couldn't call non-noexcept functions from noexcept functions. You'd never end up in `std::terminate`, but you also would need a massive update to make all existing codebases "noexcept-correct" in order to make any use of it. (and I imagine you'd need a noexcept_cast analogous to const_cast for some rare cases).

Answer (score 0):

Check out Microsoft’s static analysis tool, it can check for exactly this violation: [Don’t throw in noexcept](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/c26447?view=vs-2017)

Edit: that tool can also tell you which functions can be marked as noexcept which should make it easier to narrow down the scope of throwing functions significantly.